# What is format of below image data recieved in response body and how to save it as jpeg file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, decode

I am getting weird image data in response. Is there any Idea how I can convert this and store as .jpeg file using Node.js

```
����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000`\u0000`\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\b\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0006\u0005\b\u0007\u0007\u0007\t\t\b\n\f\u0014\r\f\u000b\u000b\f\u0019\u0012\u0013\u000f\u0014\u001d\u001a\u001f\u001e\u001d\u001a\u001c\u001c $.\' ",#\u001c\u001c(7),01444\u001f\'9=82<.342��\u0000C\u0001\t\t\t\f\u000b\f\u0018\r\r\u00182!\u001c!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��\u0000\u0011\b\u0003\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0003\u0001"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001��\u0000\u001f\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b��\u0000�\u0010\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0003\u0003\u0002\u0004\u0003\u0005\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0001}\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0004\u0011\u0005\u0012!1A\u0006\u0013Qa\u0007"q\u00142���\b#B��\u0015R��$3br�\t\n\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������\u0000\u001f\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b��\u0000�\u0011\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0004\u0004\u0003\u0004\u0007\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0000\u0001\u0002w\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0011\u0004\u0005!1\u0006\u0012AQ\u0007aq\u0013"2�\b\u0014B����\t#3R�\u0015br�\n\u0016$4�%�\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������\u0000\f\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0011\u0000?\u0000��(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(����Yi�wi\u001f��B�*g\u001b��@��@\u0016����\u0017\u0016�L�vD\u000e?\u0011���\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n��!=��0ʺ\u0015?��h�\f�\f�d�Ɩ��\u000bhվ�@?��Z�����F��6�W\u0011r}%l~�V�\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QT�MV�E����nc����;��\u000e��\n\u0000�Exf������K_\t���G�.\'Rr}B�\u0007�k�������E�����\u0000��%X#���\u0000:\u0000�z[�!�\u0000[4q�\u0000��Vuϊ4\u000b@MƷ�Ŏ��S�k爼\u000b�Ml\u0006�&�����=��P{0\u001c�c��s�xr��wG�aV\\\u001f%�f�\u0003А�\u0011�`���\u0000�R�>\r���\u0000\u0011X�\u001d�}�\u0000�5�7�_\u0005E����\u0011�;Y?�\u0015��[�V�Ky#c�\u0015?Fl���{��2�,�F9�\u0014�ց\\�K���\u001b��{\u001dNs��J��o�Y7?\u001fSi\u0016~\u001d��c5�\u001f�\u0015��X�_�zk����\u0000<���Dc\u0019M-\u0007�T7��\u0003=M�<k�s\u001e�`��s9������ħ���b�\\�\u0000���M���p�V��\u0000l�\u001f�M>3��\u0000�b}\u0014�\u0000z{�n�s}�4��B��\u0000f�O�o\u001b7Cb?ݶ���4>3ֻ\\m�\nC�=t�/\\}\t�\u000fL�\u0000�������,��\u0000�������\u0000ۑ�1�\u0000��^�\u001a���\u0006h\u001e3�\b��܏���=4�`�����\u0000���\u000f�^6���+#�֌?�y��ǉ���W��ښ�>#x�1��\r��A%\u0000zd\u001d�R��,4���R\u000f���\u001f�\u0006��H�\u0003 ���C�g����\u0017g�A����?� ��jS��\u000f��\u0007�/�\r�/��l\u000f�.\u0018U��\u0000h��\u0000��\u0004\'��������W���� ���o洭�O��1\'�T���v��\u0000d�\u0007���\u0011nz�nO�\r�?�%N��.��x~��2��W����\\��\u0000H�&�\u0000K� )���#�K�\u001f\f?�ȡ�\u0000�XP\u0007���\u0007��\u0000�i�j��\b�j�\u0007ǿ\u0007�ؖ\u001dR\u000fw�\u0004��k牼Oi<���t���\u0000\u0004&E\u001f�\u0013Q�oKo����ˆ\u0014\u0001�\u0005��_\u0002\\�myD��\t\u0017�ۊٶ��\u0000�n�\u0010x�Lbz\u0003p����!�tG�cy\u001ez��\u001f�)\f�\u0004�^�?��V�\u000f�m�;\u000b�\u0005�����\u0011ʭ��[��c�JG\u000fo�4/ش\f�~+].���\u0014i�F��h�\u0003�r�1_���\u0014\u0001��\u0015��G��\u001c _5�MQ?�>S��N?�����+\\��V���n��dI��;[��\u000fJ��[?��\u0018��$�k\'\'\u001b/�x1��\u0003�������\u0011-��3�z<N\u0018\u001f�P\u0004�QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000s�\u001c�Z��jǔ�\f�z\u0007�\u001b���\n������Z��y����|nC��t4\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QEp_\u0011~!��(R��\u0012�\u0017\u000b�4#+\u0012�\f�S�w��\u000e�k�{e\u0006y��\u001e\u0001���������\bZ�\u0000���\u0000\u001a�?�\u0017\u0017\u001a��y�kM=Ý�Z���sʷ#(�\u0011�N\u0005\u0000}�����\u0000�B���\u0000/��˟\u0014�gw�o\u0013�@���[��\u0002)�B\u0003��V�I���\\i�.�\u0019qך�Ii`cա�?��\u0000v�\u0006�����&2F�\u00001�d�;确��gb�\u0011\u001d$�����U�J�|d��\u0002��1��W�\\�\f�)�Ky�?]��:��\u0010����\u001b(��\u0003���[������OL�­C���7D4�e܌F\u000bL�N=9 ~���\u0000\u0007�;m\u001f�luۑ\u001c��JY\u001bf\u0004J\t\\\u000f~9?�zeZ����>G���\t�4����F?�<�%�3t��~��}\u0001EW*\u000b\u001f=7��\u0014��+5��?£?\u0004�T�\u0000ŧ��s�\u0000���4Qd\u0016G�g�?�\u001c`��C����\u0000����}�+�ޒ��i?���F�\\�,|�g�\u0014��4���\'�\u0000\u0011@���Q�Qҿ\u0007�&����D3���<������\u000e�\u0000�Mg�|\u0007��\u0004�1�܁�˸\nO��\u0005}GE\u001c�\u000f���\u0015��Ͷ�����\u0012�\u000f�t���\u0000\n��c�e�O��\u001a���\u001e ��Α&����\n\u0010�Te��EQܟ�Ҽ\u0017��\u001e5���\u001d\u0012+{\u0018�W)�?�x�*ZH\u000e\u000f�\u0015׌�\u0000�Y��\u0000�\u001c�&�\u0007����i�9�$q�wcn�P\u0006I�S�L���\u0017o\u0011_)=�M��\u001cS����h\u0015��~�T`C,��\u0002\u000fc�\u001a�\u0000�\u0000$q��:R����FKu�\u0004����̰�C$ҷ�HԳ\u001f�\u001c�����\u0000\u0017݄0�oS*��kvQ��_\u0003x��\u0010�\u0011�`i�z�\u000bƑ��^���8=�?\u001a��\u000b||���x�u�3�5&`��$�b\u0006\'��\f\u000fΩ%�\u000f/o�><U�tP}��D�\u0000�UV_�\u001e9����\u001b��F�F�����\u0001���\u000e|g\u0017-��K���[�VMχ��2E֑\t\u001d|�w_�_oQG"\u0003�\u0006VF���\u001dA\u0018��ھ��M���\u0000��+i��̉[��Ǹ�\u0017�����\u001c�\u0019�R-�\u001f�R�\u0003�%b��#�U�MoV�9��n��\u0000�s0��%�W�y���m\u0017�����R�\u001e\u0003s��\u0011��ԣ�\u0000f����էį\u0012ڨIna��\u0005�\nG�F\t�Mmi\u0014��Y\']\u0012;{�\\\u0019,�1�=�r?\u0003��t�\u0000\u0016�\u0014iz\u0007���|7i$1۾�ȼד(x\u000e7\u0012x<\u001f��x�KM\u0001���>4���oqwot�p\u0016��i�����?]��WӼA��R,1���\u0011��Ӯ�1�\u0001���r=�᜚�to\u0017��L+h\'7\u0016\u0001�\u000bY��S��=cou"���j��\u000f\u0000�[�RD��yd \f\u0017�d\u001e��\u0000X=���\u000fZ��\'��\u0004�\tRX�e]\u000eA\u001eƘ\u0012�E\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0001�ˈ>!۱\'7:kƾ�$\u0007�\u0000g����o�^-���8M�\u0010\u001f��#�Z��\u0000��(\u0000��(\u0000��(\u0000��(\u0000��(\u0000��(\u0001�Ȑ����cE,�z\u0000:��\u001fĺ�� �>���;%�� �\u0000\fc�\u001f�\u0015��\u0000\u0019<Bt\u0005��\u000f��To�&:������\u001f�*���a\u001c"%8P:P\u0004qH�W��9U9�ߥn�Y\b��\b�\u0017�L�\u001e�\u000e�R��K7ҷ��̇o�=3M\t�\f\u0015�/8#\u0015�F\u001a���G��W��G���J0,ϼ��\u0000�g��\u0019j?�V�S͍���H����ULm�*֞ظ\u001e��O��\u001f�(\u0006}\u0017�j�o>\u0017iAx0y���9��Wy^A�\u0002��\u0000`kZk7�z�\u0016U�\f���z�j�\u0000��)�QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QE\u0014\u0000QER��8tm\u001e�R�8��\u0016���3�ƀ<\u0007㇊�U�<z\r�����2���a����\u000f�\u0013W�\u0019\u0002�(#�յw,�������<�4�7�LI?ΰ��G��+>Ѹ�\u001d\u0007����)�#�"���[��\u0002��\'��({h�I\u0000�{�\u001d�T����^����}ߝ!��=\u0005&EN!��ד�]����K�\n��V���.\u0011�\u00012�\u0011�>e8�z\u0011ϭ0>��w�]��\u000f�K��-p��;\u0011��$\u0002~�\u0003]= \u0001T*�\u0014\f\u0000;R��\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\bn� �����%��t1�\u001b\u000e\u0019H�\u0006�W������\u0017���<�$<�I�\u0007���־����\u0016����W�%Ŭ�RH�d05-\\\u000f��½/�O�K�\tI&���.�RrOW��U�\u0000k���/zɠ\'�y-�Y#vVS��pA��^�\u0007�k�\t���`7\u001c\u0016n#��8�\u0016�\u0000h~;�W���ƥP@܇\u0007�=\u000f֚\u0003�M\'W��m\u0004���\u0006�?ys�=\b�օ|����w�\u001d��^g0��rP\u001e��Ͻ}3��\u0015X���9auY��@z������ \u001b�QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000s\u001e3�k�]\u0010v���;\u001f@C!�\u0000Ы��c�\b#�7�/ހ�0�m�)�����H�ו`\b�\u001a\u0000u\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014V\u0017�5��υ5\rU�\r\fG�\u001e�x_ր<\u000b�ψF�㋵GͶ��d�\u001d\u000b���|~\u0002���C4�G�6\u0005i�3ȱ(��L��!\'�1��fء��\'�)j\u0000����d>�@⤖p�@\u001d?�V��3!��ߚ�Y2�}h\u0001���Gm�Uy��<M��p��\n�:G>a>�ٕ�ı\u0018ˣ�q�S��\u0000����ҥ�|\\0\u001f�\u001bc�>a���m��O�O.�\u0017=\u0015�~��\u0000C@\u001e��2�E�?\u0010Ydb��9��kc�\u0000g�y���\u001a�\'H�������W��\u001d�ʏ�-}IZG`\n(��\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002���v�m<1o��ؗP�2\u0000��`��h�P���\'j�Z���BZ\u001b0-c��9c�\u0000}\u0013�Rbg�N\u0002C������ [/\u0003��Wu\u001b��Ze�#��$��\u0000\u001dE��+P�\u0011�WW��7��/��\u000f\u0015)!�mJ�z�)�\u0007�Uv�\u0012pqBU\u0019�d\f�=*��!��֌y\u0011��j��\u0007�bi4\u000br���K��s�\u001aC�pF\u000f�&E"��$�}kO·�ٞ-���m�o"f?��\u0019�3YJ~a������s@\u001fvQU���Ӧ�Ϝ�����\u0001�\u0015�\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014Q@\u0005\u0014V~��i\u001aG��u;KS���eRG�<�\u0006�\u0015�7Ŀ\u0007� 된wX܏�.+_G�\u001e���_Jԭ������e���~T��g����F��\u0019\u0018\u0010�� ��\u0011^\u0013�\u000b�y/6��$\u00189y4�q�S\u0019�\u0000�O��^�E\r\\G³A%��\f�<R�\u0015tpT��\b=)��z����u��F�����-u@���5��\u0007\u001f�?_J����\u0017ռ%����[\u0018�\u001c� �%_�)�?ɬ�h\f��\f���\u0004\u001e��\t���÷��R6�A1�������MX��S�\u001cw���@���\u001d�k\u000f\u0014ءIT\\�2������\u0000�\u001d]|W��\u0010����5���\u0006�Pxq�\u0003�}GC����\t�\u0002��\u0016I\u001c�*]\u0001�\t����py� ���(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\f\u0015ۛ�\b�\u0010\u000f��r�����ᛯ��WI��-�L~�Fh�5ȳ���pN<�9[?�\u0003\\��mT�>\t�\u0007l�a<���\u0007r�\u0000㬣��\u000e��(�\u0002�)�ʊY�*���\u0005\u0000:�þ���4��l��ؙz��M���k��~6�;N���xڝ�\u001f,V�@\'݈\u0000\u000f΀=\u001e��O�>\u0017�%h���(�^��C0�\u0006M|��ϊ\u001e%�[<r]����kjJ�\u001f�\u001e����\\ƍ��>"�b�4�W������Gvc�Tz�\u0000����ǁ��h�^�\b8�Ѽj\u0016\u0000V�~&Ц�\u0013Ŭ�<Mі�\u000eZ��\u000e�\r�t�R��\u0017M�]\u0010\t����O�~�~�J�!�H�b\u0011�Zm��k�ɅW��&�i�sس�|C�����sr@�ml�?��c��\u001f���\u0001|emm�X��mi\f�l�s�����������M��\f�\b�����3�%���n�a�=�\u0006����e)tg�C\u0005G�^���\u0000�\u0011�WZd�S4�2�O\u0003i8��i�h����\u0000\u0001RGzﵟ\r\b\u0003M��2\u000eZ\u00169 �{�\rs-�S�\u0004zV*������a�\u0007��fO�W���@~`�G��qP��\u001c�U�w*\u0017i\u0002G\u0019w$ƃ\n��zVT���<c�\'�һ\u0013M\\��E�N/tE+�\u0019\u001dq�ִu�1\u0016�*\u0001��% \u001c����\u0000�UWNAs��DI���c��r�\u0017s��N훬���z�\u0010�6Q~����Tv�1�=�wR9�@\u0016��{+�mB"|�{��S\u001d�\u0001?����5>5x\u0010ƥ��V \u0012�e���}�����N\tՄn�����5�����T,\u000fp)�Џ�?�t�\u000b��-�\u0000���\u0000�4���|\u0005�\u0000A��\u0000�I����K���\u0000�\'���<��oʟ3\u0019�o�.�\u0001�\u0000�e�\u0000�\u0012o�&��]\u001e\u0003�\u0000���,��M|��y�Dߕ\u001fg��y?�G3\u0003�8�0x\u0016N��\u000f�����i>)x"N�"�\u001f�n\u001f�W�_f��y?�K�i�y2�4s�>�O��\r~�%�G�Ӂ��Z/\u0010h�"�Z���\f�\u0013.\b�\u001c����py������i�ʑ|�2y��\u0005}��:P�+�\\��v6�e��^[��\u0016�\u0005�NH\u0015�T����)�#��OrNMk@�_۬��)$g�9\u0007ЎƢ��\b�\u0003��6�Kg2��T����BT/����9�+������x��X�\rŤ6��\u001c�\u0010��\u0005�=:�\u0015��l�.\u0017�N)M��\u0010\n\u0000�hU\u0017=\u0015�#���*��\u0007�ڼ�)�\u0007\u0018�+\u001e`T�{P"��\u0018s��v�l\n�\b��ޡu\f>�\rAH�:�I�?�+|�\u0006�3ϥ"���\u001b��x��zU�$o�\u0015��s�Ȁ)��\u0000�"���c�G�(�\u0011y}\u0016��I�\\ǿdC%e^�g\u0003���=+�,>9�J��^}�O��D�n\u0003�\\֪H\u000fK��4�\u001b�_W\u0003�:���z!�+\u001f�\u000b`��!� �\u000fB;�\\\u0005�/\u0012��GS�\u000b#��@��\'�S�r�\u0010>)��g��t�\u0015ά\u0006\u001c��ݿ�ޭ����Z���kZ�O<�\\^L�4�w;\u001e�c�\u0002��¹�~,���j�<V���g�b�ȑ��?_�\u0015�Sk�$�\'�\u001aF9/!�I��K���}CV���\u0000�Wo��\'�-c\\�G�DH��/�|\t�۽Y48n^�-���\u0017�p2H�)j��Ϛ�֧RIePH�o\u0014�}N�)�{ut�O�$`�\u000fpG5�j�1�u�1\\�m\u001c\u0019Ȇ�\u0004�A����_,�\u0000\u0018��\u0014R�\u000eU$���Ge��Z���\rf��\u001bQ���eQ��\u000f��ױ�_\u0011�/�\u0005Ak��\f��\u0000,.v��s��\t��B!�)�\fg�*�d���Y]C#\u0006SЃ�k#��\u0018��Y�I�j��H�&7\u001f~&��{\u001f�k��]OS��m;R��#��3(�\rz/��6�ټv�#�]��)��BȣԯF�0~��q��O\u0016x^��\u001e ��o�Y\u000e��\u0003�c=\u0018�\u000eGj�F*k�_��i����/Y�xnsz�\r�g?##�\u0019������pC`��j�,.$\u0018�[�\u001e�u�^��;-�\u001f�?���\u0000�\u000b��uX�ȩ���?�jD����\u0002��k�\u001b\u0018���Vp��x?����^�_\u0015���ޛz�6��:\u001d΋�\u0000-Gv\u0003���?�W�M�.����hd�@�\u000b��41�\u001b��f8��s�\u00184\r3�eִ�RF�P�\u00023���;O��R�\t[}M���\u0002�2?\f�˫<R���}qgp�.\u0019L{��\u0007�ni�9�RU��N�m�[�3�\u0011�F=D��ߏ�Yʧ+�;ha=�o\u0019k��~9c�5�\'Y#a�e9\u0007��ׂZZO��گ�5���|�i�\u001c�u8\u001fu�����xO�ޝ��6z�\u000b\u001b�!V@t��y_���5b݋��V�\\��������(��8\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�k2��v\n�d�p\u0005U��f}���)���b\u000e������\u000b�ב#B���:�8\u0002����.�%��T�Ke��\u00169?��Q���\u0015m�\n�\'w�2��X�@\u0019>6����ڥ��"^\\�\u0018�C\u0003\u0007b\u0019����\u0012OҸ߇V�߅o�cu��%�����r��u�9\u0005�\u0001\u0004~B�[�iӰ���qz~�\u0001�|Au�id\u000f��\u0000��\u001aS�\\���C{�q�\u0000�ֱ����\u001a�&�\u0000�P\u0006LZ��>$�\u0015^�I��Ҭ|Cc-���i�Q�Y\u000eB�\u0000�:\u0003��փ��rF=�P\u001b)"l�G=�\u0003�o\u001f|\u001b��%{�%L����������W�}���y\u000e��>R�\u0010�1����D�dM\r�h���\u0006�\u0004{ןx��F��\u0007k���.�\u0006�eY\u0007�^\u001f�H>�\u0001�(�%�R2;�����>6��4Il�X#�����ޠ\u0000i\u001d\u0007\t\u001a�|�rI���o�λ�K m2����;�\u0003���e\\�����Ӯ4�\u00001$�)U\u000eD��\u0019YOq�s�\u0005D�ˡ�\u001d�TNj����o��2Ϩ�M#\u001c�{�\'�Զ�֭fكP�_f����k��OƬ,��\u001f��\u0013����C\u0017M�.[#����ڀ���0��\u001d��t�X�S�\\\u000f���\'��F?\u001eEy�����8L��\r\t�\rԥ-��K7v�\\�}m!�\u0016P+��\u0006��w\u0002�FV)�\t\u0003���zs\\�a����T���\u0011,�\u0017#ta�ӎ�Sm=Ȍ�|���~��Y=�k6Უ�5��Z�c�X�\u001f�˭a��\u0003����\u0003��\b8b\u001aj���@I����\u0003������8I7����G�1W��M6��\f\u0016(�� ��u�\u0011"x��´8�V�\u0003\u001c���\u0001��S�@��\u001d�U���1L\bb�˕T����\u000f��g|O$H��\u0018��S΄F�u^EW���D��}\u0003P\u0016\u001f\u0015���$mö{~5dݞ�~]*\u001b8�n\u0017��\u0000h.\u000f\u000b\u0012�~u��{`2�m������Z\u0004�L\\\f��\u0019�q\'�J����Ц\'�����?ғ˿�\u0000�z#!�X��\u0000�s@�QG�L}�����Q��Wa힇֬���c�2\u0001�\u001a���C�X�~-@r����\u0018�\u0017��#2D��\u0004��N����hE6�\u000b�Y\u0014\u001e��#��U���/�i.�w�\u001c���\r�*!�����<�Y\n���$8�"�A�T��|�f�C�\u0004$\u000f��s�\u000ery�O�z�4Iz\u001b�=��;#n/\u0010i�r�w\u001e:t�\t�Y�3\u001c�X������G�]1�\u0000����F�2\u0016yW#\u0004`sE�r��\u000eIl�S�����A/��~���\u0000d��>d�ߊq�\u000b�e���\u0014\\V!��(�o2\b�F\u001bH�r9\u0019+�x�КҸ��\u0014�/n��8��5�c�X���[G��~����:[;|c��\u0000��Sh"C�����Dc�X�~�)<�������P�\u000b\u0014�(��F�z\u0000sN���b�\u001d�`I�F(�\u0002\u0018y\u00188�\nD/\u0010�Lc\u001e�q@�$:.�0��fe<n��q�^�a�\u0007�:/����ҢX�\u0011mm3&\u001e1�\u0003��X{���5��\u0000���\u00174\u001b��`��=�9�(Z\u0005�R�kė�1��2�%��\u0006,ORy�V��\u001f�~\u0018��km.��HP���>�\u0010�\u0019\u0007\u001fZėt��\b��la�m�I$l:\u0015r1@X�\u0007��Uyi,��O\u001f��h�f��{/\u0000\u0013�5N}K[�m����^d,�h��AW�b7c��e�{\u0016l3\u0013�H�yC���Ҁ�zkH�\\�<$z���湨��#"�/�\u001c�X�U��9r�\u001d~V\u001d\b�(\u000b"�\n\u0006E���m�?�*T��\u0000\u0004oB�!��Qū�pq\u0016�r�G�n�$�+921�7ri�,[��Vm���*1�Ɗ?*��h~��?��@�`r%`}A����\b$Y"��\u001ct`Ԯ\u0016"�X{sl/%�K�10�Kv8\u001d�5\u0003�\u001c�:7ӏ����WP�����\u001e�����x\'�S�Q@X�T��\u0004\u001a�t`.����\' ԥ\u000bpy�)�B\u000f���\f�0d�RC\u000e�u\u0015�h��Ιq��s��4`g#�p;���z��>I\u0005{zք:сվ�\u0019e9\f\u0001\u001c�t+X�5�Z��r�Zh\tn��=���@�\u0000\u0012\u001e���~��kv�M�<�����-�Fm�j7o�F�������^�\u0004��K7�\f�\u001e�\\y\'\u0000���Oj�$Ս�JQ�4]����\u0017\u000f�C\u001d���,@=1Ԛ���\u001c������i��\u001e��k\u001dE,��-��6�;�\t6"a�\u0003����Qߌ�O\u0018\u001f-�l\u0007�=+�Te}\u000f���SQ��{\u001fC|"��ƭ\u0014�\u0016�)�{h��y\u001b�\u0018�\u0000�{������S��~\u000f��Aе��_Z֡��\u0000G�<Q2�/��\u0013�=6��ڽ��\u0016���\u0000�c��\u0000�r�5�N�*���\'Nu�*jɝ�\u0015ŏ�^\u0003=<Gk�\u0000|��\u0000\u0013SG�?�s\u001cE�A!�Hݿ�՜�]Es���A�7�u;/�����\u0000�*O�K�!��J�\u0000�\f��ր7(�#�O\r��֬���6�\u0000:U���ߧ�����1�h\u0003r�ζ״k���լ\'�\u0000�W(��ր ��\u000fҀ\u0016�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002�(�\u0002����\u0010\u0000��ږ�5�A���K��^7�9��1��\u0000\u0002fE�n�\r\u0018�^���\u0019ا0�݇f#�Ƕz\u000fBM]�%��<����I�K�G�M\u0000l��B� �6�\u0000��U�N����\r**��qտJx�c�\u001e�P\u0005�*�ڈ���������>��\u0005�*%�&�"�u ���h\u00027�\u001f�0}EU{nĜ}*t�������\u0016�zƮ\u000b\u000f¦ 0�\u0014\t���e\u001b\f0\u0007��\u0016���\u0013X����v�T��6\u000f\\\u001c\u0012+�t*py\u001e����ebn�����\u001bk�\u000e��{X��4�s\u001d�&�A� \u001ft��5�-���\u0005|u�k�1\b\u001c�汵\u000f\u0006xkUm��\u0016�;�\u0000}�Pߘ���/��\n�b�gƿ�2/\u0006݇�i�py���j��o��\t��t`���"�Ѫ��\u0005|\u0013\'���\u0014�t�\u0000�K����u��.��\u000f\u001eK�B�A�)�~��?ޯ]������\u001d�u޹�5�SZ�&\'�z8.\u0014�\u0019\u0007��=�W��)&rz�u>�\u0005G\u001f�N�_�=\u0013B��|Mu�\u001dgPM<D�dn\u001dCHr>L�\u0018�Mz\r���\u000bL���M���rk�,�ƪ�[�B�u<�\u0014q\u0005��N\u0007����\u001e\u001d�}\u001bC���P�gn���>m�\u0019�i\u0014���*֝i��wl�\u0013࿅�\n����m�\tT\u0002}zT��G��\u0010ɩ�z��\u0003�Z�u�O��\u0000*�9%g\u0000?\u001d�L��h�\t�1\u001f?b�s����*k��~\u000b��id�%u^\u0000k�\tf<\u0005\u001c�$W�V\\�/5�" \u0018���`��T��\u001c��8�~\u0015�f\u0018~\u000e[�)\u0007y%�\u0019�\u0001=\u0007AVb�}��\u0014C�F\u0017�C }zסQ@\u001c0���\r�غ(��Q�\nx��K���髶��8���\u000f޵���4���^���\u0000�m]�-\u0000pG�V��OŚ��\u001b�\u001f����\u0000>��с�@\u001ex�\u001a�o�~!?¡o\t���\u0014o�`ף���E?QQ���u�?*\u0000�W�f��\u001bks�\u0000l��\u0000Z�/�t�\u001f��\u000f=�0�Pm6ٿ�\u001fCP��\u001fb��\u0006�<�_��S\u0012E���%�P��m���]\'І�����\u001f��~"�tɗ�U���<>��k/���\u0007�x��?�e���U\u00190Om7���k��ї�+/�T/d�}�ѹ\u000f��|\u0015�[\f��e\u001dԌ~������^g�����k鳦Ŝ�(O�X�Uitp��O?Ā��\u0007��M\u001f1�\\��\u001fBy�1\u000f�7N��-�����y��T\f�G�k���u�>H�kS껂��#��t+\u001e?�{!���Ryq�\u0000\u0014?�ˑ^�u��R��\u001a�9<��\u0002NJ���^�c�l��;���\u000e(�z���lz���\u0003Q�+f8\u0017a}�2*Y��ٶ�A$M�"��u\u0018J4\rG\r\u0019��)��>�L}\u000e�z@H� ���ic�%�~��\u001a\u0001JM:�?�m*�P�\r\u000b/\f�}A��\u001dZ�>�n�fPj�k��\u0013�E\'�\u000f\'���s���ȣ�#ֻ!y�O�\u0000\u001f\u0016\u00062{�\u0007�\u0015*��\u0005���U\t��o�i43��Â\u0001��(�\t���\u0000�X��O�m��\u001b�\u001fP\r@�\u000b�\u00031�\u0013�r(\u0003�\u0016��զO��\u0014����\u001d�\f}\u001f*k��º�y?g\u000f��\u0003T�Ѯ����\u001fU4�#;�\u0016�\u0000\u0019�\u0001(���Ui-g��X%���5�-\u001e#�܍�\t\u0015f+�F�a.���_\f?Z,\u0017G>0z0?J\n��鎦%��J���ٰ�Ɠo�.?��_Y1�\u0013\u0007_ʕ�s����h�\u0014�Eu\u0003�z}�:�-�v��|���Cs��v�w���\'��pߎ(\u0003�\t\u0011��=��ż\r�\u0000-��N?J�{[�f�q\u0004�7��V�\u0002�\u001c�k���hd�\r�M}&�FM��c�����8����\u000eb���\u0006�A\u0019�o$d��ן�R)�Vk��\\�N$\u0011L��*�j�L�^� z�x4Y\f�\f\u0003=(�G�>��G�xj��+�����m�u+�\u0018ʻ�/�q�#9��\u0003�P��I����1�\b5�\u0010[�-u�F!藒\'����\u0005����$�\u001f�ܟ²�4��l�֒�=W�΀5�~#|@�P"���G���(�\u0000ǁ����3��n��x;��\u0002���+�Ux��̸�52�H8�4�{�\u001fր=:�㕴�\u001a�����Z\u0006\u0003�u5���\u0017>\u001fM�M�K�9��aFQ��?�xz�\u0000e�İI\u0003\u001f�C�J�\u001a\\\f�_E\'�/֋\n�Ӛ_��\u0013�������ۤr^K\u000b�,ºȗύd��f��1�\u001c~d\u001c����w����Ve�_�S��R�L�d���m$S��fL~\u0000 i��\n\u0002Ϝ\u000e�����)7AF�(��H \u001f�_1�\u001f\u0018<c�\u0005F�R�5�\u001bȃ��a��k��>?@�SY�%�w��@�{�l\u001fȚ\u0000��.n�\r�����\u001f�\u0015\u000bj�\u0019��]{����\u0000B��Y\u001a/�O\n��V�W�f#�E���\'�\u001b\u0019?L�B�\u0010\u0019�\n�u#�΀)\u001f\u0010��}$�{�\u0003�?21S��iwR\b��m$��E�K\u001f�9�\u00040J2�~\u0006��|;a|�n,��\u0007�zD\t��\u0000mQ\\��2X�>���@�Q%%\u0007�\u001b+�U��5k~%�=��3���O�\u0004P\u0006�\u0015�\u0006���n-���\u0000x����s��\u0015�\u001c�*\u0007����e9\u0014\u0000�(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\n(��\nᤕ��i�N��v�\u001b(��\u000b�9��Q�\u0000\u0001�渐\u0002^�?_2�Wϯ́�\u0001@\u001ah�\u0000/=iAb�\n�\u0011��kB\u0018�u=(\u0000�2�5i!�\u0015$1\u00003V�P\u0005#\u001e��D�\u0002�\u0019\u0006*����4\u0001U��ɨL�n�JY�;�d��$g�\u0000jC2I2�eEb8�S_Y�=��k��\u0018\u0005N\u000e+˼O�+�\u001fQ\u0012�b�\u0019\u0014eN�P���\u000f��Sh^1յ\u0014�e�=�g\u0019��y�g\u0019�\u0002���E�i���9��G6���Њ�4]zK�>+���~�\t�#�?*�����L��W�����\u0012�\u0003�\u000fb8?�_��]������U!}�&͡��\u000f��\u0014\u0001��,w1\u0006^A�=*E\u0018��KmE��ާ�ⷭ�;y���>��/g\u001dzTOs\ngt���sP̞yܲ�_���Tx]G*GҀ->�n��\u001f��I�Ek\u0002�c���\u0007��)ԀMsz�\u001d�\u0001�\fo�>7���V������#\n�\\`\u0010��\u001f�|�G<��b�4�����3��A�qIᏃ�=�\\�SE%�6V�\f����z\u000fa@\u0012�\u001f��D�ė�C8+e\u001b\u000eB�\u001aOǠ�M{d\u0007j�T\u0016�p�5UP�@\u0000\u0001���\u0002���\u0005\u0000858HG94y\'�\u001eI��\u0000���(����棵�u��N\ty���P\u0017�ȟƘSg�FB��z��Em\u001b-� ��\u0001��\u000f?ր4>��\u0000��T�mU���\u000e)�0�\u000b�\u0000koU������\'�����Y���wku\u0014p\u0018�6fB�Y�\'\u0019Q��}�6��\u001aM�#�\u0017M�է��U�k��u\'�-��5�!��0l�������\u001d�Z��քh��\u001d\rH�\u0018�~�A\t�Q��\u0014���(�\u0002�(�\u0002�\u0014�P\u0001Q4\u00117%\u0006}@�h�\n�d���>��\u000fhG���+@�w�\u00194\u0001�m���*������U�\b�֡kpz\u001cP\u0007;q��8"H���3�ΨK����<����ǰ9\u0003�\u0015�Ilz����o�M\u0000q7z;ȥ%��u<bxq��O?�r��������&�s�v�+~�/�\u0001�W{n1��%��A��\u0000x=��ǎM�:�e��a�C\u000b��\u000f�\\����oI_2�M�a�\u0013"�C�\u0000\u0002\u001cW��XnFF\u0001��R2\u000f�Vkh�D������L\u000eS#�\u0003�\u0000��%\u00078=:�T���۵?\bX�9k�+Y��z4~S�\u0000�q��\u0000A?Z��\u000f�h2�7�Z��\\��\u001f�����I��\u0015�\u0019^�\u0004\u001fJ�}�MwM\f��\u0019�^�Z��G�\u000eGЌ�Jˆ�O#�=)�&�\b���7d�\u0000u��\bu[�H\tr�=$\u0001�\u0019%���Zb����k��\u0000[o\u001b��\u0015�\u0018�Mh�K\u001c��\u0000��\u001f��E\\\u001a�[�h��v���7�\u0003m!=�3�4�4\r*q�\u0000_�\u000e+�*��(8�\u0015,o4\u001f�n&��\\���a�Mټ!f��;��\u0019���"��L��b�5}N!���=$_�*a�9�\u0013Y��\u001b\u0003F�dc����\u0004+TQ�ڕ�f�i���\u0000�r\u0015�:V����>q*��\u0011�,ߤ���p�]5�~\u0015�r�^��n"\u0019?��d������tIl��\u0000�KV����U����J�=j��\u0019?�\u000f�E��xoK��i:�R\u001f��7\f=�Jͼ���e�%�u\u001f�\u0017�?JK�2\u0019\u001br���\u0007��4���Ł\u0002���\u0007��w\nC�3v���GPh�{\n�\u0005�z�x�l�/�\u0000=\u0014`�}��\u0014c}�����Q�Ӱ�c��\u0015,2�n۠�H�b�EJb��t�\u0017F���5�\\\u0003*N����En[x�)\u0006��\u0002=J\u001d���7e4���Q��4��\u000f�,��\r����\u000fN�K��:����\\!L����\u0016׷�g6�R��\u001b�ʀ/�x>�ԝ�+�ݫ\u0012m:{v�!R;������mGn&�/�`�y�e�\u001d���ӑLL͇V�,�Y���d\u0019�z������.�d����F^�N&O�p}ꔐ\u001f����7\u000e�kt�f�~\u000f�\u0012\u001c��k6�����\u0000�Bʹ��*\u001a�"�6܅���+V�V��l����F�p*��\u000ep}2+{E�ǈ�<W�/W��1�\u0000,]�ȏ���\u001f�+&�m\'\u0006H�ɓ�\u001d\u000f�Y��u�$�j��;\f�^!�����9�~�6?�שh\u001e1ѼF��u�.�\f�\fvʿTl\u001eƾ>i\u000f�\u000b;$�"3,�r��\f�B9\u0014\f��o~m�&�;T�ɗ�\'�C_/xk�?�4UX/�Mf�q����\u000fi\u00079��^��o�\u001e\u001b�[,\u0016w�d�n>�xB9?��F�\u000eh\u0003���7�\u0001�zƞ����uvH%`�b�\u0018ߢ䎪I��pq�Z�<�v� ��T�\b����A�ȥHϯ�\u0000Q���ٱ8���\u0001\\C�V�7\u0011O���#�<\u0011�Uk@.�bw9p\n��2�v��L��[\u0012�r\u0012\b����@\u001atVb^�\u0001�2��w\u0018\r�\u0007��j�\u0017\u0011\\�h�0\u0007\u0004t �\u0011�P\u0004�QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000\u0014QE\u0000Awp��Sܰ��\u001bHG�\u0019�?Ӯ%��\u0014��|�\u0001$�\u0000\u0017R\u000f�Mv>$`<=v\t��P�\u0019�?θ\u000by�^z\u001c�4\u0001�Ap\u0002������j�1�v\u0002��8�Ys�0}��X�爴�\u001e0���P\u0016�\u0006?3}\u0007Z\u0000�b�E��\u0015Ԩ��]\u0005��7Q\t"p��\u0006�&��:\u001e�7�k��ғ�>P��q��4}j]6�0$�O̾��=\\���2���+��-�h�\u0015a��\\l>�\u0001�r\u0006\u001a��\'y����\f\u0007�b\\�,y�@\u001c����|��Cq�5[H�"�a�mv�ȧ\u0006)3�=F+n�y5H���\u0000I}q6�b�7~\\����ܟ����R��oag\u001d��K\u00141�*/A�\u001a�\u000f���\u00064\u0001��\u001e�*�GF�k-d#�J�b���[���J���:��c���Y�&{w�S%��H\u000b3���\u000f�c{�\\���\u0019�R�\nrppjk��\u0015�-���:\u0000�Ю�\u0000\r%�\u0003�9�v�����\u0007̜wZ��m�j0+M@�\u000e�/����\t���-����?F�$�р?��\u0001�\u0005C�\u001f����p�,��du�\u0013V\u0013Q�N�/�3�\u0000���o�H��8\u0011�>���1��G�8\u0018�;W,5�Ē \\?%���1�j�x�a��F�\u001cP\u0006��v\u0014�\b��f��#?~�����]zɾ��Ϫ�\u0005�\b�\\/�M\\��X\u0018���Y\u000b�����pqՎH\u0000\u000f�j�\u0017S����>�\u0005����\b��Y\u0004M�\n�\b�G4���8�;���v�Ϧ�ar\u0007��y�䟙�>dc=J\u001e\u000f�z\u0010k�Q��\u0016z.���,�v�\u001bI�oE\u001e�?�p3���Y�څ�\u001c���O\u0010,B����\u0005\u0001F\u0005Ak\u0010�<��ܟoj�L�h��\u0000(���\u0000Z(��\ni8��\u0014���0�ր\u0000;���a�\u0007�\ni�<}��\u0014\u0001-\u0015\u0017�\u001f�\u001f�82�B\r\u0000>�cS�S�\u0000\u0012O\u0003�r���/\rh!�Π�H�R\u001f������\u0007D�����\u0007�\u0007�J�]K���3&��\u0019}\u000b1l�\u0003�ֱ��?\u0017_7�\u001e����UF?<�\u0007�����Z��\n�8�u�\u0012當�_f�\u001f�jv���KT/6��\u0011��6Ҥ��3@\u001e�����=��Ҽ�~7�ZM�jZl��>�Ko��ץni�\u0000\u00194+�\u000b:\b����΀:Yt�fߴ\u0006\u001d\u0018\u0012\b�\u0011��+\u0013T1ye\u0005�`̻\\}\u0019p\u000fη��Q��X\u0010�"��\u00165��$���\\z��\u0000xΥ��5,�e���\r�̿���Er:���hcu���\u000ex�>x��\u00042?:�2[.�:��{E���\u001e�\u0018\u000e��GCF����s\u0002\u0001\u0004`�\u001d�\u0000\u001a�&��T�\u000f���B\t$��\u001bK�\t\u0013��E\'գ\u0000��\u0000�לk\u001e\u0013״\u0018�{�X��\u001f��j�H���e?�C��qX�e\u001e���VOz�[��@�\u0007�\u0004�\u0000�H�R\u000f�N��?�N�,Ѱ\u001cz�T���E����/���\u0000�<^�{F?3@��"\u0001��4=UO�T��/������z_�K���O��\u0002i�41�E�\u00054�\u0011�\u0001Q��z��\u0014Q�\u001f����@\u0012}�#����\u0016p����\u000f�ݤn���)�s�do��\u0002�7��8\u0015\u001b�{�<�����\u0000|��SY�&�"h�zS\n\u000fJ���#�K�\u0014�s̍�\u000f��,3`#�M1�T��\u0000m�
```

Above is just part of image data.

Comment: pass the string to a Buffer and `toString('base64')` it to get the base64 of the image.

Comment: @JayGould Do I have to unescape the characters in image data like these '����'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code

```
path = '/home/fileName.jpeg'
var fd = fs.openSync(path, 'w');
fs.write(fd, body, 0, body.length, 0, function(err, written) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error ' + err);
  }
  console.log(written);
});
```

Comment: here body in your response